# Shiny: can't add color, icon or subtitle to my valuebox

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

I built my first dashboard using `shiny` and I wanted to add some valueboxs but when I did it the valuebox appeared without color or subtitle or icon.
[image]

I can't figure out what is the error. Please help and thanks in advance.

Here's the code I wrote:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
Base_Ferias <- read_excel("C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/R/Apps/Seguimiento_ferias/Base_Avance_Ferias.xlsx")
Base_Ferias$T_respuesta <- as.numeric(Base_Ferias$T_respuesta)



ui <-dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                   dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard", titleWidth = 450),
                   dashboardSidebar(selectInput("actividad", "Select", 
                                                choices = Base_Ferias$Actividad)),
                   dashboardBody(
                     box(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("chart"),width=200,
                                  title="Percentage"),
                     box(valueBoxOutput("value1"), height = "100px", width = 3)

                     )
                   )



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$chart <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    x <- Base_Ferias[Base_Ferias$Actividad==input$actividad,]
    y <- x$T_respuesta
    gauge(y, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%')
    })

  output$value1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste0(25,"%"), "subtitle",icon("stats",lib='glyphicon'),
             color = "purple")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching `flexdashboard` last masks functions with the same name from `shinydashboard`. Use `valueBox` from `shinydashboard` instead:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box

ui <-dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                   dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard", titleWidth = 450),
                   dashboardSidebar(selectInput("actividad", "Select", 
                                                choices = c("one", "two"))),
                   dashboardBody(
                     box(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("chart"),width=200,
                         title="Percentage"),
                     box(valueBoxOutput(outputId = "value1"))

                   )
)



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$chart <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    x <- 1
    y <- 10
    flexdashboard::gauge(y, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%')
  })

  output$value1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste0(25,"%"), "subtitle",icon("stats",lib='glyphicon'),
      color = "purple")
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5809
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It doesn't work either, but I figured out that that there's something wrong in my RStudio configuration because the same code worked well in another Windows computer.

Comment: Also, do you think that there could be a problema using the shinydashboard and flexdashboard at the same time?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, if you load `flexdashboard` after `shinydashboard`, functions with the same name (such as `valueBox`) will come from `flexdashboard`. Try restarting your R session and copy and pasting the example code I provided. Also, you should provide a minimal reproducible example in your question. We don't have access to files on your computer, so the code example you provided won't run for people trying to help you.

Comment: I was able to make it work detaching `flexdashboard`, but in other computer (I'll try to reinstall R in mine).
Really thanks